# How do I highlight the whole text in a line that triggers syn-containedin?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Suppose I have these Vim definitions:

```
syn match tasktag "\(\s\)\@<=@[a-zA-Z0-9_]\+"
syn match taskdone "\<[Dd]one\>" containedin=tasktag
```

How do I specify `taskdone` to highlight the entire text in the line? I looked at [`:h syn-pattern-offset`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-pattern-offset) as well as [`:h syn-region`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-region).

Answer (score 0):

First, your "tasktag" match does not allow spaces or other "word delimiters", yet your "taskdone" match requires "done" to be a discrete word because of your \< and \> word boundary atoms.

Second, your "taskdone" match is written to only highlight the word "Done".

Assuming I properly understand what you want, I modified your two matches:

```
syn match tasktag "\(\s\)\@<=@[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]\+"
syn match taskdone "@.*\<[Dd]one\>.*" containedin=tasktag
```

If you haven't done so already, you will need to specify the highlighting for the two matches.  For example:

```
highlight link tasktag TODO
highlight link taskdone Statement
```